# Настройка темы для Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, шаблоны, html, php

Здравствуйте.

Раньше я только верстал всякие Landing page, сейчас же необходимо сверстанный шаблон (не лендинг, а многостраничник) натянуть на Drupal 7.
Дело в том, что я понятия не имею, как это сделать, точнее я пытаюсь HelloWorld'ы всякие, и то не получается, то непонятно, как он стили находит, когда не должен, куда админ панель верхняя пропадает, в общем, жуть.

С версткой-то проблем нет, я наверстал все страницы необходимые, на JS тоже наваял всего, но вот перенос на Drupal - вообще беда, просто шаблон с одним параграфом и то проблемы вызывает (пропадает админка, и не входит в нее).

Не подскажите какие-нибудь уроки, видеоуроки... по этому поводу (создания и настройки шаблона для Drupal), прям вообще с нуля чтобы, прям с верстки начиная, потом как, что и куда резать, что откуда берется?..

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общий принцип такой:
Конечный вид шаблона собирается из различных файлов и настроек в процессе рендера.
Для всех элементов есть свои шаблоны и стили по умолчанию, они в ядре. Чтобы их переопределить, надо создать свою тему или подтему от другой темы (в этом случае унаследуются также ее шаблоны и стили).

Для этого надо как минимум создать папку `/sites/all/themes/MYTHEME` и поместить в нее файл `MYTHEME.info`.
В нем задаются общие сведения, пути к css и js файлам, регионы для вывода блоков (если отличаются от стандартного набора).
Этого уже будет достаточно, чтобы тема заработала.

Для внесения изменений в разметку можно переопределить, например, шаблон вывода страницы, это файл `page.tpl.php`. Но перед тем как это делать, я бы рекомендовал разобраться, как он работает на примере другой темы, например: https://www.drupal.org/project/html5 (файлы с шаблонами *.tpl.php могут находиться в подпапках).

Чтобы в процессе рендера Drupal вставил блоки содержимого в шаблон, надо, чтобы в файле присутствовали вызовы соответствующих функций.
Другие файлы шаблонов отвечают за вывод других блоков и сущностей. Их достаточно много.
Также есть возможность переопределять сами функции вывода в файле templete.php, но это уже потребует знаний api drupal.

Хороший урок по созданию шаблонов с нуля: http://drupalfly.ru/lesson/mask_generation_drupal_7_1
Там несколько частей.

Удачи.